# Proof of the local section theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'd like to make out Lee's proof of the theorem that if $\pi$ is a smooth submersion, then every point of $M$ is in the image of a smooth local section of $\pi$. The statement of the theorem and its proof are enclosed herewith.

=========================

[image]

===================================================

My question is why the image of $C_\varepsilon$ under $\pi$ is $C_\varepsilon'$. I don't see how that is possible. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: The hypothesis $|x^i| < \varepsilon$ gives $\pi (C_{\varepsilon}) \subset C'_{\varepsilon}$. Conversly, if $(x^1,\ldots, x^n) \in C'_{\varepsilon}$, then $(x^1,\ldots,x^n) = \pi(x^1,\ldots,x^n,0,\ldots,0) \in \pi (C_{\varepsilon})$.

Comment: Thank you, but how did you relate the coordinates $(x^1,\ldots,x^m)$ to $C_\varepsilon'$? I got stuck in the step of showing that $\pi (C_{\varepsilon}) \subset C'_{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: Because if $|x^i| < \varepsilon$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$, then so it is for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, provided that $n \leqslant m$ !

Comment: I have no doubt about what you are saying. Indeed, it is genuinely true. But, is this fact really the reason for $\pi (C_{\varepsilon}) \subset C'_{\varepsilon}$? To illustrate this, please let me denote the coordinate map for $(x^1,\ldots,x^m)$ by $\phi$, the coordinate map for $(y^1,\ldots,y^n)$ by $\psi$, and the $i$-th coordinate function by $r_i$. If $x\in C_\varepsilon$, then $|r_i(\phi(x))|<\varepsilon$. On the other hand, if $y\in\pi(C_\varepsilon)$, how did you know that $|r_i(\psi(y))|<\varepsilon$? Thank you.

Comment: I just made it! The critical point is to take the special coordinate representation of $\pi$ into account!

Comment: @Didier If it is convenient for you, could you tell me why the map $\sigma$ is well-defined? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can carefuly define it with the special coordinate representation: something like $\Sigma = \phi \circ \sigma \circ \psi^{-1} : \{(y^1,\ldots,y^n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid |y^i| < \varepsilon \} \to \{(x^1,\ldots,x^m) \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid |x^j| < \varepsilon \}$ with $ \Sigma(y^1,\ldots,y^n) = (y^1,\ldots,x^n,0,\ldots,0)$. $\sigma$ is then equal to the map $\sigma = \phi^{-1}\circ \Sigma \circ \psi$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question can be found in the comment, and I would like to thank Didier for his/her kindly help. Finally, for those who fail to complete the check that $\sigma$ is a local section of $\pi$, try to conclude that $\hat{\pi}\circ\hat{\sigma}=\mathrm{Id}$, which should be immediate from the coordinate representations of $\pi$ and $\sigma$. Then you can extract $\pi\circ\sigma=\mathrm{Id}_{C_\epsilon'}$  from this equation by pulling the coordinate maps out of the composite. Hope I'm not mistaken.